# OSGI dependency issue with Sling Models project

Tags: maven, osgi, aem, sling

I'm having a slight problem with incorporating the appropriate maven dependencies into my project for sling models.

When I deploy my bundle, I get the following import that can't be resolved:

org.apache.sling.models.annotations,version=[1.1,2) -- Cannot be resolved

I believe I have included this with the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.impl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I tried using:

```
<Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
<Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
```

in my bundle compile instructions, but this has just resulted in a ton of other dependencies not being resolved.

Surely I've gone down the garden path here somewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.apache.sling.models.api V1.0.2` bundle does export the following packages:

```
javax.inject,version=0.0.0
org.apache.sling.models.annotations,version=1.1.0
org.apache.sling.models.annotations.injectorspecific,version=1.0.0
org.apache.sling.models.spi,version=1.0.0
org.apache.sling.models.spi.injectorspecific,version=1.0.0
```

So if that bundle is active in your Sling instance, the `org.apache.sling.models.annotations,version=[1.1,2)` import should resolve.

Note that adding bundles to your maven dependencies might not be sufficient to install them in the running instance, what matters is whether the models.api bundle is active as seen from `/system/console/bundles`

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. Spot on, the api bundle wasn't loaded. I've marked the bundle I'm using Sling Models in to be tagged with <Import-Package>*,org.apache.sling.models.api</Import-Package> in the configuration instructions. Any tips for what else I might be missing?

Comment: Saying `Import-Package: *, org.apache.sling.models.api` is surely redundant, since the models.api package will be covered by the preceding wildcard.

Comment: Whether the bundle is loaded in your Sling instance or not has nothing to do with pom dependencies in general - you'll need to load the bundle via the usual mechanisms. If the Sling installer is active the simplest might be to add the bundle to an install folder in the content repository.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Embed-Transitive` is almost always a terrible idea. It traverses the entire transitive dependency hierarchy in Maven and pulls each one of those JARs into your own JAR. As a result you inherit all the package dependencies of all that crap you have dragged in.

When you have a bundle such as yours that requires an import -- in this case `org.apache.sling.models.annotations` -- the best solution is to find another bundle already available that exports the same package.